# Cannot insert html after placing less-than signs in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where I need to generate a form fieldset template and save it inside a hidden element. When a user needs to add more fieldsets to a form, the template is read and inserted to the bottom of the existing form. To make sure the template doesn't interfere with jQuery selectors I've replaced all less-than signs and quotes with %LT!% and %QOT!% respectively, and the idea **was** to replace these with the proper signs again when the template was being inserted, but for some reason it isn't working.

To show the situation in code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    %LT!%span id=%QOT!%testing%QOT!%>Hello%LT!%/span>
</div>

<span id="target"></span>
```

JS:

```
htmlstring = $("#test").html();
htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(/%LT!%/g, '<');
htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(/%QOT!%/g, '"');
$("#target").before(htmlstring);
```

It won't work as long as the second line has the less-than sign. Placing any other character there instead works just fine, but like that absolutely nothing gets added to the page. What's going on here?

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BnEbP/)

Comment: try using [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)  &lt; &gt;

Comment: It would be easier to create a dummy element, then when you need a new one just [clone it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode), then [append the clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things you should use the proper HTML encoded entities. Also rather than hiding the `div` you can just store the template in a data attribute.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->    
<span id="target" data-template="&lt;a href=&quot;#test&quot;&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;"></span>

<script>
    htmlstring = $("#target").data('template');
     $("#target").before(htmlstring);
</script>
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than what I had in mind, and most importantly it works. Thanks!